# Fourier algebra and multipliers of a finite discrete group

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a finite discrete group. We denote by $A(G)$ the Fourier algebra of $G$ and $M_{cb}A(G)$ the space of completely bounded multipliers of $A(G)$.

Is is true that $A(G)=M_{cb}A(G)$ isometrically?

Comment: Finally, It seems to me that it is true for compact groups. We have $A(G)=B(G)$ for compact groups according to Eymard p209 and $B(G)=M_{CB}A(G)$ for amenable groups according to Haagerup/Cannière "Multipliers of the Fourier algebras" p465.

Comment: This seemed to be more a comment than an answer. Feel free to merge it into your question if that is a better disposition.